# Play Framework: *pickBranch* and *or*

Tags: json, scala, playframework

In the following statement, `pickBranch` returns a `Reads` ...

```
((__ \ 'firstName).json.pickBranch)
```

... on which I can invoke `or` like this:

```
val emptyObj = __.json.put(Json.obj())
((__ \ 'firstName).json.pickBranch or emptyObj)
```

If `pickBranch` succeeds, then `or` returns the result of `pickBranch`, otherwise it returns `emptyObj`.

Now, is it possible to invoke `or` on the `Reads` returned by `pickBranch` and pass either `emptyObj` or what `pickBranch` returned?

```
val emptyAllowed = true
((__ \ 'firstName).json.pickBranch or (if (emptyAllowed) emptyObj else >>>RESULT OF pickBranch<<<))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution. First, I've created an *extensions* object for `Reads`:

```
package object typeExtensions {

  import play.api.libs.json._
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit class ReadsExtensions(reads: Reads[JsObject]) extends AnyVal {

    def orEmpty = reads | __.put(Json.obj())
    def orEmptyIf(b: Boolean) = if (b) orEmpty else reads 
  }
}
```

And here below is how to use it:

```
val canBeEmpty: Boolean = true
((__ \ 'firstName).json.pickBranch orEmptyIf canBeEmpty))
```

For more details, see my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860351/278659).
I hope that helps.